# How let function that wrote by vimscript concurrently run？

Tags: vim

I know that using `job` and `channel` in vim can run external procedures concurrently, but I want to concurrently run function which wrote by vimscript and in `*.vim` file.
How I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is impossible.

At best you could start another vim process and run your function in this other process. The current instance won't be affected -- for instance it won't be possible to add thousand of keywords to highlight in the background.